# Processing certain URL in apache when configured with Websphere application server, plugin-cfg.xml

Tags: apache, plugins, url-rewriting, websphere-7

I have configured Drupal apache server with WAS using the mod_was plugin. Now certain URI have to be processed by the drupal server and these URI come under the URI configured in plugin-cfg.xml

EX:

```
 this the URI inside plugin-cfg.xml:
 <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/foobar/*"/>

 But the URIs /foobar/new and /foobar/[ID] , ID being a variable have to be served by drupal.
```

I saw this URL [Blocking url on web server (websphere)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12379585/blocking-url-on-web-server-websphere), but they only talk about block certain URI but not serving those blocked URI in apache.

Answer (score 0):

The answer should be here: [WebSphere reverse proxy plugin - skipping domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59978983/websphere-reverse-proxy-plugin-skipping-domains)
`SetEnvIf Host ^dimsim\.domain\.com$ skipwas=1` (I was looking for a similar question.)